# Slow response in fetching records from Apache Phoenix using Java

Tags: java, apache-phoenix

I am fetching data from Apache Phoenix using Java. The java client is executing query on the phoenix query server. I have added the below dependencies in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.phoenix</groupId>
    <artifactId>phoenix-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.14.0-HBase-1.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.phoenix</groupId>
    <artifactId>phoenix-queryserver-client</artifactId>
    <version>4.8.1-HBase-1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Below is my java code:

```
public class SamplePhoenixConnection {

    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:phoenix:thin:url=http://<IP>:<PORT>;serialization=PROTOBUF";

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement st = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("org.apache.phoenix.queryserver.client.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL);
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            conn.setReadOnly(true);
            conn.setSchema("DL");
            st = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,
                    ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
            st.setFetchSize(100);

            String sql = "SELECT DISTINCT EMPLOYMENTSTATUS, EMPLOYEECODE , DESIGNATIONNAME, DATEOFBIRTH, BAND FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE TENANTID = '10'";

            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

            while (rs.next()) {
             System.out.println(rs.getString(1) + " : " + rs.getString(2) + " : " + rs.getString(3) + " : "
                    + rs.getString(4) + " : " + rs.getString(5));
            }
            rs.close();
            st.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (st != null)
                    st.close();
            } catch (SQLException se2) {
                se2.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                if (conn != null)
                    conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                se.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Although the phoenix cluster is properly configured and I have also enabled the required salting and indexing on the phoenix table, but the code was still taking time to fetch the records. To debug further, I added time logs to check which section is consuming more time and I found that the below section is consuming roughly around 1.5 seconds per 1000 records:

```
while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1) + " : " + rs.getString(2) + " : " + rs.getString(3) + " : "
                        + rs.getString(4) + " : " + rs.getString(5));
            }
```

Even if I remove the print part of the loop and keep only `while(rs.next()){}`, it is still consuming almost the same time. What could be the fix for this slowness?

Comment: What is rowkey for the table, TENANT_ID ?

Comment: There is an index on TENANT_ID and I am not selecting the rowkey. Even if I select rowkey, time taken is the same.